# php + postgres unknown error inserting data to my DB

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Well, i have a problem trying to insert data in my DB, the conexion works fine ( i have inserted other things before).
This is the view (all is working fine here):

```
<form action="../../Controlador/agregarAlumno.php" method="post">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre Coordinador" required="true" />
    <label for="email">Rol:</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="rol" placeholder="Rol USM" required="true" />
    <label for="nombre">Rut:</label>
        <input id="nombre" type="text" name="rut" placeholder="Rut" required="true" />
    <label for="email">Área:</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="area" placeholder="Área" required="true" />
    <label for="nombre">Teléfono:</label>
        <input id="nombre" type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Ej: +56988182965" required="true" />
    <label for="email">Talla Polera:</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="talla" placeholder="Ej: S, M, L" required="" />
    <label for="nombre">Carrera:</label>
    <select name="carrera">
    <option value="">Elige una carrera</option>
    <?php 

        foreach($carreras as $carrera) 
        { 
           echo '<option value="'. $carrera[0] .'">'. $carrera[2] .'</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select>

    <label for="email">Correo Electrónico</label>
        <input id="email" type="mail" name="correo" placeholder="Ejemplo@ejemplo.com" required="true" />
    <label for="email">Contraseña</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="contraseña" required="true" />


    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

This is "AgregarAlumno.php", i make some echos and the data come fine.

```
<?php

   include("../Modelo/alumno.php");
   $al = new alumno();
   $al-   >agregarAlumno($_POST[nombre],$_POST[rol],$_POST[rut],$_POST[telefono],$_POST[talla],$_POST[   carrera],$_POST[correo],$_POST[contraseña]);

?>
```

Here i have the function, the file is alumno.php:

```
  function agregarAlumno($nombre,$rol,$rut,$telefono,$talla,$id_carrera,$correo,$contraseña)
 {
     include("conexion.php");
     $query = "INSERT INTO alumno VALUES('".$rol."','".$id_carrera."','".$nombre."','".$rut."','".$correo."','".$contraseña."','".$telefono."','".$talla."')";
     return $result = pg_query($query);

 }
```

This is the table where i'm trying to insert the data.

```
 CREATE TABLE alumno
 (
 rol character varying(20) NOT NULL,
 id_carrera integer NOT NULL,
 nombre character varying(20),
 rut character varying(20),
 correo character varying(100),
 pass character varying(30),
 telefono character varying(20),
 talla character varying(3),
 CONSTRAINT usuario_pkey PRIMARY KEY (rol),
 CONSTRAINT usuario_id_carrera_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_carrera)
  REFERENCES carrera (id_carrera) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
 )
```

I don't know where is the error, hope someone can give me a hand. (I'm so sorry, i posted so much code)

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL Injection / Eres vulnerable a inyección SQL.

Comment: I know, but i don't care this time...

Comment: You should not include conexion.php everytime you call the function, it may generate errors.

Comment: Ehm still not working, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy and paste your function in agregarAlumno.php and try :D